# How to pass Multiple selected checkbox value to the server using api in android?

Tags: java, php, android, json

I have a "Service" table in the database and I get the services using adapter class for service selection in the checkbox. It shows the service with a checkbox. I want to place the order which is selected by customer through checkbox. I need to pass the selected checkbox data to Api. But how to pass multiple checked checkbox values to the server?? Help me.

Here is my code

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_get"
    android:layout_width="91dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:text="Place Order"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/recycler_view"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/recycler_view"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.72"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

Service.java

```
public class Service {
@SerializedName("laundry_service_id")
@Expose
String laundryServiceId;
@SerializedName("laundry_service_name")
@Expose
String laundryServiceName;
@SerializedName("laundry_service_short_form")
@Expose
String laundryServiceShortForm;
@SerializedName("laundry_order_status_id")
@Expose
String laundryOrderStatusId;
@SerializedName("laundry_service_create_by")
@Expose
String laundryServiceCreateBy;
@SerializedName("laundry_service_join_date")
@Expose
String laundryServiceJoinDate;
public Service(String laundryServiceId, String laundryServiceName,
               String laundryServiceShortForm, String laundryOrderStatusId,
               String laundryServiceCreateBy, String laundryServiceJoinDate) {

    this.laundryServiceId = laundryServiceId;
    this.laundryServiceName = laundryServiceName;
    this.laundryServiceShortForm = laundryServiceShortForm;
    this.laundryOrderStatusId = laundryOrderStatusId;
    this.laundryServiceCreateBy = laundryServiceCreateBy;
    this.laundryServiceJoinDate = laundryServiceJoinDate;
}

public String getLaundryServiceId() {
    return laundryServiceId;
}

public void setLaundryServiceId(String laundryServiceId) {
    this.laundryServiceId = laundryServiceId;
}

public String getLaundryServiceName() {
    return laundryServiceName;
}

public void setLaundryServiceName(String laundryServiceName) {
    this.laundryServiceName = laundryServiceName;
}

public String getLaundryServiceShortForm() {
    return laundryServiceShortForm;
}

public void setLaundryServiceShortForm(String laundryServiceShortForm) {
    this.laundryServiceShortForm = laundryServiceShortForm;
}

public String getLaundryOrderStatusId() {
    return laundryOrderStatusId;
}

public void setLaundryOrderStatusId(String laundryOrderStatusId) {
    this.laundryOrderStatusId = laundryOrderStatusId;
}

public String getLaundryServiceCreateBy() {
    return laundryServiceCreateBy;
}

public void setLaundryServiceCreateBy(String laundryServiceCreateBy) {
    this.laundryServiceCreateBy = laundryServiceCreateBy;
}

public String getLaundryServiceJoinDate() {
    return laundryServiceJoinDate;
}

public void setLaundryServiceJoinDate(String laundryServiceJoinDate) {
    this.laundryServiceJoinDate = laundryServiceJoinDate;
}
```

}

ServiceAdapter.java

```
public class ServiceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ServiceAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private static List<Integer> mSelectedItemsIds;
List<Service> serviceList;
//private List<Integer> mSelectedItemsIds;
Context context;

public ServiceAdapter(List<Service> serviceList, Context context) {
    this.serviceList = serviceList;
    this.context = context;
    mSelectedItemsIds = new ArrayList<>();
}

public static List<Integer> getSelectedIds() {
    return mSelectedItemsIds;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View  view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.service_layout,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Service serviceClass = serviceList.get(position);
    holder.chkbox.setText(serviceClass.getLaundryServiceName());

    holder.chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                mSelectedItemsIds.add(position);
            }else{
                mSelectedItemsIds.remove(position);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return serviceList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CheckBox chkbox;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        chkbox=itemView.findViewById(R.id.chkbox);
    }
}
```

}

CheckboxActivity.java

```
public class CheckboxActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<Service> serList;
CheckBox checkBox;
int id;
Button btn_get;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkbox);

    checkBox = findViewById(R.id.chkbox);
    btn_get = findViewById(R.id.btn_get);


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    LinearLayoutManager LayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(CheckboxActivity.this, 
    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(LayoutManager);

    btn_get.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           viewService();
        }
    });

    Call<List<Service>>call = RetrofitClient
            .getInstance()
            .getApi()
            .getServices();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Service>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Service>> call, Response<List<Service>> response) {
            serList = response.body();
            ServiceAdapter serviceAdapter = new ServiceAdapter(serList,CheckboxActivity.this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(serviceAdapter);
            id = serList.size();
            Toast.makeText(CheckboxActivity.this,"Get the services"+id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Service>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(CheckboxActivity.this,"Try It" + 
    t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println(t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

private void viewService() {
    List<Integer> selectedid =  ServiceAdapter.getSelectedIds();
    //Log.d("List","=");
    Toast.makeText(CheckboxActivity.this,"Clicked"+selectedid,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedid.size(); i++) {
        int chk = selectedid.get(i);
        if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
            String ch = checkBox.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(CheckboxActivity.this,"Data"+ch,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
}
```

Api.java

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("place_id.php")
Call<OrderResponse> place(
        @Field("list") List<Integer> selectedid);
```

I tried the above code. Service.java class I get all service responses to show in recyclerview with a checkbox. Now I want to pass the selected checkbox value to the server. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **adapter** class you are adding the **position** to the list **mSelectedItemIds**.

`mSelectedItemsIds.add(position);`

What you should be doing is adding the field from an object of `Service` class into that list. So let's say you want to pass the `laundryServiceId`s of the selected checkboxes to the server. Then, in that case you should do something like this:

In your adapter, change the type of list item to String:

`private static List<Integer> mSelectedItemsIds;`

In your adapter's `onBindViewHolder` :

```
if(isChecked){
mSelectedItemsIds.add(serviceClass.getLaundryServiceId());
}else{
mSelectedItemsIds.remove(serviceClass.getLaundryServiceId());
}
```

And then pass `ServiceAdapter.getSelectedIds()` to the server when you want.

*I hope this solves your problem, if there's any confusion then feel free to comment.*

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sir. It Works. how to get those ids in php file. I tried to access but it shows an error  Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 Column 1 path $

Comment: I don't know php. But, since now you're passing a list of string(becuase getLaundryServiceId returns string), you would need to modify your API on both ends.

Comment: There is any other way to send the list to the server?